# Sending data type as command parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, itemssource, commandparameter

I have a list view, which items are defined using `ItemsSource`.
The `ItemsSource` is a list of local class type.
I need to send as a `CommandParameter` the selected items `DataType`.

Can someone help me with this?

Code: (This code is in the App.xaml and the data template is inside an itemsTemplate tag)

```
<Application.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="xxx" DataType="BL:DeviceInfo">
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectDeviceCommand RelativeSource={RelativeSource ancestorType=ListView}} CommandParameter="{???????}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

I wand to send the SelectedItem as a Deviceinfo , which is the type of the items of the list that is the items source of the list view.

Comment: What did you try so far? Show some code, then we might be able to help.

Comment: *I wand to send the SelectedItem as a Deviceinfo*... what `SelectedItem`? *the data template is inside an itemsTemplate*... please show us that... and what collection control are you using? Please provide *all relevant code for your problem*.

Comment: Can you not send the _item_ by using `{Binding}` and then do a `.GetType()` in your converter to get `DataType`?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest is:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

This will send the DataContext object itself as a command parameter. Then you can derive it's type in the handler for the command.

If you NEED the type itself to the sent as a parameter you'll need to create a converter.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter(v=vs.110).aspx